# how to judge source of drag action is from sidebar of finder or the source is kind of a device or mounted dmg

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Basically, as Destop & energy saving of setting, at the Folders, you can drag any folders into it, I designed an app, which has the same function, recently I received a bug, which says, if you drag a mounted device from sidebar to it, a blue line will appear, I tried on this native setting, it will not occur the blue line, I think Mac OS X has a way to judge the drag source and disable this drag, so the blue line will not show. But I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to return `NSDragOperationNone` in your

```
(NSDragOperation)draggingEntered:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender
```

implementation indicating that "No drag operations are allowed" (and read up on Drag and Drop programming in Cocoa: [Introduction to Drag and Drop](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DragandDrop/DragandDrop.html)).

My guess is you're currently always returning `NSDragOperationCopy`.

Comment: I returned None for this kind of drag on delegate tableview:validateDrop:proposedRow:proposedDropOperation:, but still, there will be a blue line shows there.